# Linux, switch file permissions from root to normal user

Tags: linux, files, users, root, gid

The file made after running Alphafold2 database is saved with root authority. As a normal user without sudo authority, how can I switch a made file from root to my own? and what if I have root access?  *I know my GID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have root access but you do have write access to the directory, you can copy the file and then delete the one owned by root.  (If you don't have write access to the directory, you probably can still at least copy it.)

If you do have root access, you can use the `chown` command.

Comment: Copying the file will only work if read access is given.